# where i can download rcFile extensioin tamplate file for testing

Tags: python, templates

- I want one rcfile to testing and coding purpose.
- Is there any website where i can downloand template by just giving their extension name.
- 

Answer (score 0):

you can install pylint and generate one.

```
pip install pylint
```

in the terminal run `pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc`

Comment: Not its not working can you write one example of this

Comment: you can see example here https://github.com/ozshalom/envalidate/blob/main/.pylintrc